# Best way to edit nested list for specific problem?

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a question and different ideas on how to approach it, but I'd like to know what more experienced programmers would do.

**Background:**
I have a nested list, with sub lists, that always have two items, that looks like this: [[category, item];[category, item];...]. categories and items are strings. There are items that end with a number or float and there are others, that end with just characters or spaces. Some (but not all) items are duplicates.

**Problem:**
Just focused on the items, categories do not need to be altered. Do not suggest to use dict or something else, it needs to be a nested list like above.

1. I need to delete every duplicate, that does not end with a number/float - so just one of the 1-10 duplicates remains in the list.
2. If there are duplicates (same items), that end with numbers, I need to sum up all numbers/floats and just leave one entry with the summed up number and delete the original ones.

**Example:**

*Input:*

```
[["fruits", "Apple 1"];["fruits", "Apple 2"];["fruits", "Apple 5"];["cooled", "iced tea 1,5"]; ["cooled", "iced tea 2"]; ["fruits"; "onions"]; ["fruits"; "onions"];["fruits"; "onions"];["frozen"; "Pizza"]
```

*Output:*

```
[["fruits", "Apple 8"];["cooled", "iced tea 3,5"];["fruits"; "onions"];["frozen"; "Pizza"]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me

```py
from collections import Counter

vals = [["fruits", "Apple 1"],["fruits", "Apple 2"],["fruits", "Apple 5"],["cooled", "iced tea 1,5"], ["cooled", "iced tea 2"], ["fruits", "onions"], ["fruits", "onions"],["fruits", "onions"],["frozen", "Pizza"]]

counters = {}
others = {}
for sub_list in vals:
    items = sub_list[1].rsplit(' ', 1)
    try:
        num = float(items[-1].replace(',', '.'))
        if sub_list[0] not in counters.keys():
            counter = Counter({items[0]: num})
            counters[sub_list[0]] = counter
        else:
            counters[sub_list[0]].update({items[0]: num})
    except:
       
        others[sub_list[0]] = sub_list[1]

my_result = []
for key, counter in counters.items():
    items = [[key, f"{sub_key} {value}"] for sub_key, value in counter.items()]
    my_result = my_result + items
my_result = my_result + [[key, value] for key, value in others.items()]
print(my_result)
```

output

```
[['fruits', 'Apple 8.0'], ['cooled', 'iced tea 3.5'], ['fruits', 'onions'], ['frozen', 'Pizza']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This worked. The numbers are always floats now. Can you help me to only use floats were there is a need for decimals? So every full number would be rounded to full numbers?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
entries = [["fruits", "Apple 1"],
           ["fruits", "Apple 2"],
           ["fruits", "Apple 5"],
           ["cooled", "iced tea 1,5"],
           ["cooled", "iced tea 2"],
           ["fruits", "onions"],
           ["fruits", "onions"],
           ["fruits", "onions"],
           ["frozen", "Pizza"]]

counts = {}
categories = {}
for category, entry in entries:
    try:
        value = float(
            ''.join(
                re.findall(r'[\d,.]*\d', entry)).replace(',', '.')
        )
    except ValueError:
        value = 1

    item = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z]', entry)[0]
    categories[item] = category

    try:
        counts[item] += value
    except KeyError:
        counts[item] = value

result = []
for item, count in counts.items():
    result.append([
        categories[item],
        item if count == 1 else f'{item} {count}'.replace('.', ',')
    ])
```

A bit more string/float/int formatting would be needed though to exactly replicate the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It did work, but it also adds numbers to the ones, that didn't have numbers before, like "onions". It's a good step though :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would start, by transforming your list into better data. Instead of having strings with two items, you should have tuples where the first item is `Apple`, `onion` etc. and the second item is either a float or None. You can use regexp to do this work easily.

```
import re

def transform_to_tuple(data):
    m = re.match(r"([A-Za-z ]+)( \d+(,\d+)?)?$", data)
    if m:
        return (m.group(1), float(m.group(2).replace(",",".")) if m.group(2) else None)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Malformed string '{}'".format(data))

data = [["fruits", "Apple 1"],["fruits", "Apple 2"],["fruits", "Apple 5"],["cooled", "iced tea 1,5"], ["cooled", "iced tea 2"],
        ["fruits", "onions"], ["fruits", "onions"],["fruits", "onions"],["frozen", "Pizza"]]

betterdata = [(x[0],transform_to_tuple(x[1])) for x in data]
```

Once this is done, iterate over the list of tuples and working with the data will become a lot easier.